# AngularJS $http.get won't work with node.js RESTful

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest

I have a problem with my AngularJS application. I build a Node.js RESTful API for simple GET and POST functions. If I use a test client to send the http-request, all worked fine and I get my data back.
But if I try to use the same request in my angular-js application, I got an error and I don't know why.

here is the code of my node.js app

the www.js:

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');

var port = '3000';
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/v1/', routes);
app.use('/api/v1/users', users);
```

users.js:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    db_pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            conn.release();
            res.json({"code": 100, "status": "Error in connection database"});
            return;
        }

        console.log('connected as id ' + conn.threadId);
        conn.query("select * from Users", function (err, rows) {
            conn.release();
            if (!err) {
                res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
                res.json(rows); // fetch rows
            } else {
                res.json({"code": 404, "status": "No Users available"});
            }
        });

        conn.on('error', function (err) {
            res.json({"code": 100, "status": "Error in connection database"});
            return;
        });
    });

});
```

And here is my Angular-JS code:
app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('tutorialApp', [])
    .controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users').success(function(usersResponse) {
            $scope.users = usersResponse.data;
        }).error(function (response, status, header, config) {
            alert("ouh, an error...");
        });
    });
```

and the HTML-Site:

```
<script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/modules/app.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">

    <p ng-show="search">You searching for: {{search}}</p>

    <table class="table" ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">
            <td>{{user.user_id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

what do I wrong?

Comment: Try using $http.get('/api/v1/users') instead of full URL

Comment: Isn't it a cross-domain error?

Comment: I started the angular-js app without any server behind (just double-click the html-file from File Browser). If I put an static json-file in the $http.get function, it worked. But without any server, I couldn't use relative URLs, do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after I use node.js for serving my angular-page and reduce the URL to a relative URL, all works fine. Thanks for your help.

Now my UsersCtrl looks like:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('tutorialApp', [])
    .controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('/api/v1/users').then(function(usersResponse) {
            $scope.users = usersResponse.data;
        })
    });
```

Comment: FYI it's uncouth to answer your own question unless the info was not already provided - what you did above was provided by answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely due to the following deprecation:

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

via https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Try using more streamlined code with success/failure callbacks and relative urls when it's the same host :

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Which for your code would look something like:

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(
  function(usersResponse) { $scope.users = usersResponse.data;},
  function (res) { alert("ouh, an error..."); }
);
```

Also, I highly recommend [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular), I feel it's much easier and efficient than $http alone. It's built on top of $http, just a more contextual and user-friendly setup.

Comment: I wish when people gave a down-vote, they would share the reason in a comment. Is there misinformation here? Did they dislike that I recommended a different module? I believe I still answer the question as OP asked it.